# LaTeX: PART in TOC is not on the right place

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I have a question related to my TOC,

```
\mainmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{Part I: Near Infrared Spectroscopy\par}
\include{chapters/chapter1}
\include{chapters/chapter2}
%...
\include{chapters/discussion}
```

For some reason, the Part I is on the wrong place:

[image]

Who knows why this happends??

Greetings,

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The section layout in your toc is not the default one. We really need to see a [mre] if we should format the part in the same way.